# Call child component based on state value in parent component using React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass data to child component(grid) from parent component. In parent component, I have created a state for the data which gets updated once the data fetch from an api is finished. Currently, I check if the state length is greater than 0 and only then I call child component.

```
const ParentComponent()=>{
   const [gridData, setGridData] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => { getDataFunction (); }

   const getDataFunction = async () => {
       try { //apis to get data } 
       setGridData(apiData);
  }
          
  return (    
     {gridData.length > 0 && <ChildComponent Grid tableData={gridData}} 
  ); 


   }
```

The above code works fine. It displays the data when there is some value in gridData. But I would like to display an empty table while the api is being called. Or if the api has no data, even then an empty table needs to be displayed.
Child component:

```
const Grid = React.forwardRef(({ tableData, columnData,  ...props}, ref) => {
let activeColumn = [...columnData];
const onGridReady = params => {
        setGridApi(params.api);
        setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi);
        setGridRowData(tableData);
        params.api.applyTransaction({ add: tableData });
    }
return (
  <AgGridReact
      onGridReady={onGridReady}
      columnDefs={activeColumn}
      pagination={true}
  </AgGridReact>
);
});
```

If I just use gridData instead of gridData.length, then even after the value of the state is updated, the table is not updated. It will always be empty even if later the data is fetched from an api. How do I make child component update when gridData state changes ?

Comment: How do you use gridData in your child component ? Maybe you just use the incorrect props in your table

Comment: `{ gridData.length === 0 ? your empty table : your child component }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
return (   
<> 
  {gridData.length > 0 && <ChildComponent Grid tableData={gridData} />} 
  {gridData.length === 0 && <div>Hi there</div>}
</>
  );
```

You simply render it conditionally based on length

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. But basically I am writing the code twice right if I want to display the same grid but only in empty state? Will this be considered efficient ?

Comment: @user2128: yes this is perfectly normal and considered efficient. If this answer helped you to resolved your issue, do remember to mark it by pressing the `tick` icon, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope you have written useEffect code properly, bcoz the syntax seems incorrect.

useEffect(() => {

   const getDataFunction = async () => {
       try { 
       setGridData(apiData); 
}    
  }
     getDataFunction()
      },[])    
  return (    
      <ChildComponent Grid tableData={gridData}
  ); 

Use gridData.length > 0 line while rendering your child component
```

and for Empty Table while loading you can use Skeleton on loading state.

Comment: Wouldn't the function go into infinite loop ?

Comment: Correct. The dependency should not be there.